# In SQL server 2019, one encryptionkey and multiple decryptionkeys (one decryptionkey per user) to encrypt/Decrypt Columns of a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2019

In SQL server 2019, I have a table having 10 columns. There are 10 user logins. Each user should see only three columns as per their choice.
I need to keep the data encrypted in the database. Even admins can not see the data (until a decryption key is shared with them).
each user logins should be granted access to the columns they need. There much be overlapping column choices among the user logins. Each user logins will be given their unique decryption keys to decrypt the encrypted columns. One decryption key per user. this single decryption key should decrypt all three columns of their choice.

As a solution, I thought of one encryption key to encrypt all columns of my table and multiple decryption keys (one decryption key per user) to Decrypt Columns of the table.
Read access will be granted to each user only to the columns selected by the user.

Please suggest how this can be implemented.

Comment: I'm just spitballing here, but what if you had one encryption key per column and you granted (or not) permission to the key based on whether the user should be able to decrypt the column? Though, stepping back, what are you trying to accomplish with the encryption/decryption scheme? If it's just "users shouldn't see data that they're not allowed to", would just regular column-level permissions suffice?

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for the suggestion.

The table contains Sensitive data which is why encryption is a must. 
I suggested having 1 encryption key per column. thus we shall have 10 keys. we shall share only those keys to the user that they need for their required columns to decrypt. This way regulating grant on select will not be required. the key will do all the work. 

But this Idea is rejected asking for more security.